# error booting computer

Tags: boot

boot error on machine with invalid MOK keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you setup a [Boot-repair](https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso/download) live USB and try to repair the boot from it ?
Can you upload the PasteBin of the repair (by default after boot-repair operations).

Comment: thanks for the tip, i solved this issue some time ago and i dont completely remeber how i solved it but i did have to repair the EFI partition with a live usb.